# Why does my webbrowser not save my javascript output?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a simple piece of code.. I created a calculator to calculate Celcius/Kelvin/Fahrenheit based on HTML input. The code seems to be working. The correct answers appear but then dissapear in a split second, the browser seems to 'refresh'. Am i missing something?

Html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="degrees">Degrees: </label>
    <input type="text" name="degrees" id="degrees">
    <label for="calc_type">Type: </label>
    <select name="calc_type" id="calc_type">
        <option value="celcius">Celcius</option>
        <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">

  </form> 
  <table style="width: 100px">
<tr>
    <th>Celcius: </th>
    <th id="celsius_value">0</th>
    <tr></tr>
    <th>Fahrenheit: </th>
    <th id="fahrenheit_value">0</th>
    <tr></tr>
    <th>Kelvin: </th>
    <th id="kelvin_value">0</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<script src="js/celcius_calulator.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var degrees = document.getElementById('degrees').value
    var calc_type = document.getElementById('calc_type').value

    if (calc_type === "celcius") {
        cC(degrees);
    } elseif (calc_type === "fahrenheit"); {
        fC(degrees);
    } elseif (calc_type === "kelvin"); {
        kC(degrees)
    }
}

function cC(degrees) {
    celcius_value = degrees;
    kelvin_value = degrees * 273.15;
    fahrenheit_value = degrees * 1.8 + 32;
    document.getElementById('celsius_value').innerHTML = degrees;
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit_value').innerHTML = fahrenheit_value;
    document.getElementById('kelvin_value').innerHTML = kelvin_value.toFixed(2);
}

function fC(degrees) {
    celcius_value = Math.round(degrees - 32) / 18 * 10;
    kelvin_value = degrees + 459.67 / 1.8;
    fahrenheit_value = degrees;
    document.getElementById('celsius_value').innerHTML = degrees;
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit_value').innerHTML = fahrenheit_value;
    document.getElementById('kelvin_value').innerHTML = kelvin_value.toFixed(2);
}

function kC(degrees) {
    celcius_value = degrees - 273.15
    fahrenheit_value = degrees * 1.8 - 459.67;
    kelvin_value = degrees;
    document.getElementById('celsius_value').innerHTML = degrees;
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit_value').innerHTML = fahrenheit_value;
    document.getElementById('kelvin_value').innerHTML = kelvin_value.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Your inputs are in a `<form>`, and the form is submitting. Lacking an "action" attribute the default behavior will be to reload your page.

Answer (score 2):

The submit button will post the form-content to whatever you specified as the form's target through `<form action="target-url">`. As you didn't specify anything, it will simply post the forms content to the current page.

You will have to do something like

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault())
```

to prevent the form from being submitted, which will then again prevent the page from reloading.

You can then also do your evaluation logic in the event listener so you don't end up with two event listeners (One for the submit button, one for the form submit event).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to pass an `event` as parameter in `myFunction(event)` and do event.preventDefault(). Just pass event as param the following ->

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction(event)">
```

and in your js file do this ->

```
function myFunction(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var degrees = document.getElementById('degrees').value
var calc_type = document.getElementById('calc_type').value

if (calc_type === "celcius") {
    cC(degrees);
} elseif (calc_type === "fahrenheit"); {
    fC(degrees);
} elseif (calc_type === "kelvin"); {
    kC(degrees)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the below change in your code.

```
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Hope this solve your problem.